# Facebook Graph Api: How to get formatted page posts

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api

I am using the graph api (javascript) to get the posts posted by the admin of a Facebook page which works fine so far. The API returns a string containing the post text.

**Problem**: Is there a way to get that string with "style"(e.g. line break) information as the admin formatted it?

**Example:**
*Facebook page original post:*

"Hello this is a cool post of me.

One in a while we like to post news.

If you like our products feel free to contact us."

*Facbook API return value:*
"Hello this is a cool post of me. One in a while we like to post news. If you like our products feel free to contact us."

**ANSWER**: Found an answer: decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(message)))